# CORS is not getting enabled even after adding cors npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have written an upload API to upload CSV files from the front-end. I am sending CSV files as form-data to API. When I am calling upload API. I am getting this below issue in the browser console suddenly. Previously it was working.

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/config/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:3005' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

**POST http://localhost:4000/config/upload net::ERR_FAILED**

This is the code for API call.

```
static uploadCapps(data) {
   const { files } = data;
   const uri = API_BASE_URL + "/config/upload";
   console.log("=====files", files)
   return axios({
            url: uri,
            method: 'POST',
            data: files,
    headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
             },
        }).then((response) => {
            return response
        }).catch((error) => {
            return error
})}
```

Comment: In the image, there are request headers. The `allow-origin` is a response header

Comment: I am getting CORS issue suddenly. So I made changes in the header in request Object as  allow-origin.

Comment: @CristianTraìna, Could you please help me to slove this issue.

Comment: please, improve the format of your post. Someone had fixed it before, but it broke again after your last edit